# How can I add a separator in between words in a userform, except the last word?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a code that fills a textbox with the captions from selected checkboxes automatically. Here is the code:

```
If PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox1 = True Then Mark1.NEWPITCHSTYLETEXTBOX.Value = Mark1.NEWPITCHSTYLETEXTBOX.Value & PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox1.Caption & " - "
If PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox2 = True Then Mark1.NEWPITCHSTYLETEXTBOX.Value = Mark1.NEWPITCHSTYLETEXTBOX.Value & PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox2.Caption & " - "
If PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox3 = True Then Mark1.NEWPITCHSTYLETEXTBOX.Value = Mark1.NEWPITCHSTYLETEXTBOX.Value & PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox3.Caption & " - "
```

My issue is that I want to put separators in between the captions without putting a separator after the last one. For instance, leaving the " - " if there is nothing coming after it.

Comment: Put the caption *before* the text you're adding, but only if the existing TBOX content is not empty.

Comment: @TimWilliams so basically add an if statement that checks if the tbox is empty, and if its not, use the above code but flip the tbox value and the caption?

Comment: something like `If PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox1 = True And Mark1.NEWPITCHSTYLETEXTBOX.Value = "" Then Mark1.NEWPITCHSTYLETEXTBOX.Value = Mark1.NEWPITCHSTYLETEXTBOX.Value & PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox1.Caption
ElseIf PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox1 = True Then Mark1.NEWPITCHSTYLETEXTBOX.Value = PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox1.Caption & " - " & Mark1.NEWPITCHSTYLETEXTBOX.Value
End If`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a "helper" method:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    '...
    '...
    AddCaptionsIfChecked Mark1.NEWPITCHSTYLETEXTBOX, PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox1, _
                        PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox2, PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox3
                           
End Sub

'add the caption from each checked checkbox in `checks` to textbox `txtBox`
Sub AddCaptionsIfChecked(txtBox As Object, ParamArray checks() As Variant)
    Dim cb
    For Each cb In checks
        If cb.Value Then
            txtBox.Value = txtBox.Value & IIf(Len(txtBox.Value) > 0, " - ", "") & cb.Caption
        End If
    Next cb
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice ParamArray solution +:) ...Fyi You might be interested in my post slightly modifying your contribution

Answer (score 3):

An alternative, slightly modifying Tim's valuable contribution, would be the following approach (considering also empty text inputs):

- `a)` join (param) array via defaulting *space* delimiter
- `b)` followed by a text split, with the text being smoothed beforehand using `Application.Trim` to eliminate empty text inputs:

```
Sub connect(txtBox As Object, ParamArray checks() As Variant)
'a) Join action
    Dim tmp As String: tmp = Application.Trim(Join(checks))
'b) eventual Split action 
    txtBox.Value = Join(Split(tmp), "-")
End Sub
```

**Note** `Application.Trim` (rather than VBA's `Trim` function) allows multiple spaces to be reduced to a single one.

Answer (score 1):

### Populate Textbox Dependent on Checkboxes

```vb
Sub PopulateNewPitchStyle()
     
    Const DELIMITER As String = " - "
     
    Dim NewText As String

    If PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox1 Then NewText = NewText & PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox1.Caption & DELIMITER
    If PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox2 Then NewText = NewText & PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox2.Caption & DELIMITER
    If PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox3 Then NewText = NewText & PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox3.Caption & DELIMITER
    If Len(NewText) > 0 Then NewText = Left(NewText, Len(NewText) - Len(DELIMITER))
    
    Mark1.NEWPITCHSTYLETEXTBOX.Value = NewText

End Sub
```

Comment: close to OP ... and keeping it simple by just removing the last delim +:)

Answer (score 0):

Please try :

```
    If PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox1 Then
        sTxtVal = Mark1.NEWPITCHSTYLETEXTBOX.Value
        Mark1.NEWPITCHSTYLETEXTBOX.Value = PITCHSTYLESPOPUP.CheckBox1.Caption & IIf(Len(sTxtVal) > 0, " - " & sTxtVal, "")
    End If
```