# Multi-select Combobox with comma separation between selections - making sure no comma at end

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, multi-select

I am using the below VBA code to put comma separation between combobox (lstHomeroom) multi-selections. However, my code is giving me a comma at the end of the list. How can I amend my code to remove the comma at the end?

**For example:**
Don't Want: selection1,selection2,selection3,
Want: selection1,selection2,selection3

```
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim Homeroomselected As String

For y = 2 To x

        'Update Homeroom
        For Z = 0 To lstHomeroom.ListCount - 1
        
            If lstHomeroom.Selected(Z) = True Then
                Homeroomselected = Homeroomselected & lstHomeroom.List(Z) & ","
            End If
            
            Next Z
            Sheets("Input").Cells(y, 4).Value = Homeroomselected

Next y
```

Comment: I didn't think you could use multiselect on a combo box. Did you mean a listbox? Either way this would achieve what you're looking for. Sheets("Input").Cells(y, 4).Value = Left(Homeroomselected, Len(Homeroomselected) - 1)

Comment: My mistake, Listboxes, yes thank you.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common task to concatenate an unknown number of strings, including a separator character (in your case a comma). If you have an array of values, you can use the VBA function `join` for that, but in your case this will not work because you don't have an array and you want to add only the selected items.

Basically, there are two ways to solve this issue.

The first is what you currently do in your code, always append the separator character, and when you're done, remove the last separator. This is what @Tom suggested in the comments:

```
Homeroomselected  = Left(Homeroomselected, Len(Homeroomselected) - 1)
```

This has a small problem: When nothing was selected, you will get a runtime error as the Len of the string is 0, and -1 is not a valid parameter to the `Left` function. To be sure, you will need to check for that:

```
If Homeroomselected <> "" Then
    Homeroomselected  = Left(Homeroomselected, Len(Homeroomselected) - 1)
End If
```

And, if you change the separator to let's say `", "`, you need to remember that  now you need to remove 2 characters.

What I also don't like so much is that the string in invalid until the very last moment. You have to ensure that the last character is always removed. Consider you have a loop to create the string and decide for whatever reason you have enough data and want to exit (for example the maximum length or maximum number of elements was reached). You need to ensure that the statement to remove the last character is always executed, so you can't simply issue an `Exit Function` statement.

The second method is to check if we need the comma at all. As we cannot tell in advance if another element is to be added later, reverse the logic: Before you write an element, check if there was already an element. If yes, add the comma to the existing element.

```
If lstHomeroom.Selected(Z) = True Then
    If Homeroomselected <> "" Then
        Homeroomselected = Homeroomselected & ","
    End If
    Homeroomselected = Homeroomselected & lstHomeroom.List(Z)
End If
```

Which can be written in short using the `IIf`-function:

```
Homeroomselected = Homeroomselected & IIf(Homeroomselected <> "", ",", "") & lstHomeroom.List(Z)
```

Or, you could create a small routine:

```
Sub JoinString(ByRef result As String, element As String, Optional Separator As String = ",")
    result = result & IIf(result <> "", Separator, "") & element
End Sub
```

and use it like that:

```
If lstHomeroom.Selected(Z) Then
    JoinString Homeroomselected, lstHomeroom.List(Z), ","
End If
```

Comment: Wow, what a thorough response! Very clear, and has really helped my primitive understanding of VBA. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You could also add your selected values to an array and use `Join(array, ", ")`

Comment: @Tom: Yes, but the bad thing about that is that you don't know the size of the array in advance, so either you need an initial loop to count how large your array needs to be or you need to use Redim preserve statements. Both would make the code more ugly, and you again have the issue that only at the end of the procedure the result is created (so no Exit function or the like).

Comment: @Tom fyi c.f. my approach via paramArray function: [How can i add a separator in between words .. except the last word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76942174/how-can-i-add-a-separator-in-between-words-in-a-userform-except-the-last-word/76947316#76947316)